# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getstate__' " shows up when I use easy_install

Tags: python, django, easy-install

For some reason, every time I attempt to install a new module using easy_install, I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getstate__'
```

I'm using setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-distutils-sig/13989/: the gist is "reinstall setuptools".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but the solution was that i had two versions of setuptools: one was in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.6.egg/ and one was in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/. the former was an outdated version, but /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages is earlier on my path. i removed the old one, and was good to go.

Comment: In my case I found several of files that seem related to `setuptools` (incl. files that have `easy_install` in their names). I removed all as far as I've found and reinstalling `setuptools` worked. Thx

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the same as **jessykate** mentioned, but the exact opposite.

I had to REMOVE the version installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ and KEEP the version located in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/  This was on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `yum reinstall python-setuptools` and run the `easy_install` command again.